# sql replace with variable value

Tags: sql, variables, replace, sql-update

In SQL I would like to replace limit n per family with nothing, where n can be 1-100.  how do i do that?  I tried...

```
update t set field1 = Replace(field1,'Limit%per family','')
```

and nothing updated.

Comment: Which RDBMS / database software are you using?

Comment: Do you have that string literal in your values for field1? If so, do you not have any spaces in it? It really isn't very clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX together to accomplish this:

```
DECLARE @str CHAR(100)
SELECT @str = 'other text Limit 4 per family some more text'

SELECT REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('Limit', @str), CHARINDEX('family', @str)-6),'')
```

For me, it returns: "other text  some more text"

All you have to do is plug in the last select statement to your update call and replace @str with field1